Blazor WebAssembly Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'out') after Publishing
I am encountering an issue with my Blazor WebAssembly application after publishing it. The application works fine in both development and release modes, but once I publish it, I receive the following errors:
 dotnet.js:3  MONO_WASM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'out')
    at $l (https://ident.lordist.in/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.6.71pl3usugk.js:3:198913)
    at ze (https://ident.lordist.in/_framework/dotnet.js:3:30902)
    at https://ident.lordist.in/_framework/dotnet.js:3:30138
    at async Object.create (https://ident.lordist.in/_framework/dotnet.js:3:34517)
    at async https://ident.lordist.in/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:43466
    at async https://ident.lordist.in/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:58010
    at async mn (https://ident.lordist.in/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:57613)
u @ dotnet.js:3
dotnet.js:3  Error in mono_download_assets: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'out')
Q @ dotnet.js:3
9dotnet.runtime.8.0.6.71pl3usugk.js:3  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'out')
    at $l (dotnet.runtime.8.0.6.71pl3usugk.js:3:198913)
    at ze (dotnet.js:3:30902)
    at dotnet.js:3:30138
    at async Object.create (dotnet.js:3:34517)
    at async blazor.webassembly.js:1:43466
    at async blazor.webassembly.js:1:58010
    at async mn (blazor.webassembly.js:1:57613)
blazor.webassembly.js:1  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to start platform. Reason: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'out')
    at mn (blazor.webassembly.js:1:57654)

Details:

Application URL: https://ident.lordist.in/ Repository:
https://github.com/jitendrajadav/SLTDentalViewer Development
Environment: Works fine in both development and release modes.
Published Environment: Errors occur after publishing.

Steps to Reproduce:
Develop the Blazor WebAssembly application.
Test it in development and release modes (both work fine).
Publish the application.
Access the published application at https://ident.lordist.in/ and encounter the error.
What I've Tried:

Ensuring all files are correctly published and accessible.
Checking for any differences in configurations between development
and published environments.
Reviewing the published files for any missing dependencies or
corrupted files.

Question:
What could be causing this error after publishing, and how can I resolve it? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

How you create this webassembly? Did you create this webassembly inside the low version and update the version to the 8?

.NET 8 and I have tried 8.0.4, 8.0.5 and 8.0.6 all are getting same error

How you test this application? Publish it to the IIS and test it or you directly running the exe?
